# Is the mapred process in Hadoop multi-threaded?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I've configured our hadoop cluster with mapred_map_tasks_max to 6 and as expected, I see 6 mapred processes running when kicking of PIG jobs.

I am however a bit surprised to see the CPU usage on some of these individual processes to exceed 100% sometimes reaching 1000%+. Does mapreduce default to multiple threads? Could this be something with Pig itself?

All I could find online was some information about a setting (mapred.map.runner.class), but this doesn't appear to be set to MultiThreaded in anyway.

Thanks.

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 2630 mapred    20   0 53.4g 2.8g  12m S 218.1  4.5   1:17.32 java
 2553 mapred    20   0 53.4g 2.8g  12m S 110.7  4.5   1:25.07 java
 2636 mapred    20   0 53.4g 2.8g  12m S 110.4  4.5   1:11.58 java
 2437 mapred    20   0 53.5g 5.6g  12m S 108.1  8.8   3:46.52 java
 2353 mapred    20   0 53.5g 5.2g  12m S 101.1  8.3   3:35.27 java
 2239 mapred    20   0 53.5g 5.8g  12m S 82.6  9.3   3:54.47 java

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with Hadoop to use a multi threaded mapper (see http://kickstarthadoop.blogspot.com/2012/02/enable-multiple-threads-in-mapper-aka.html). As far as I know, pig doesn't support multi threading jobs (although you can multi thread calling Pig Servers... https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-240).

That said, Pig will by default run multiple mappers/reducers on the same host, one mapper/reducer per available core.